# how to get the value of SAME XML tag byStaX using java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax

I am trying to retrieve values from xml document. 
  The XML Size upto 3gb. so i choose the StaX parser using java. 
  Here i used the below code to retrieve the values in between the tags. 
  If i execute the code then i got the values from one   tag. 
  I want the three  Tag values.

```
<Author>
  <Number>1</SequenceNumber>
  <Role>B01</ContributorRole>
  <Name>Klaus Misgeld</PersonName>
  <NameInverted>Misgeld, Klaus</PersonNameInverted>
  <BeforeKey>Klaus</NamesBeforeKey>
  <KeyNames>Misgeld</KeyNames>
 </Author>
 <Author>
  <Number>2</SequenceNumber>
  <Role>B01</ContributorRole>
  <Name>Karl Molin</PersonName>
  <NameInverted>Molin, Karl</PersonNameInverted>
  <BeforeKey>Karl</NamesBeforeKey>
  <KeyNames>Molin</KeyNames>
 </Author>
 <Author>
  <Number>3</SequenceNumber>
  <Role>B01</ContributorRole>
  <Name>Klas Amark</PersonName>
  <NameInverted>Amark, Klas</PersonNameInverted>
  <BeforeKey>Klas</NamesBeforeKey>
  <KeyNames>Amark</KeyNames>
 </Author>

  Same XML Tag...
```

How to retrieve the values from the same xml tag?

I tried
  XMLReader.java

```
 XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
            XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
           if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
               StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
               if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Product")){
                   emp = new BookSpecBean();

               }
               //set the other varibles from xml elements

                     if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Author")){
               else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Number")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   emp.setSequencenumberchar(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Role")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   emp.setContributorrolechar(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Name")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   emp.setPersonnamechar(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("NameInverted")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   emp.setPersonnameinvertedchar(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("BeforeKey")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   emp.setNamebeforekeychar(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("KeyNames")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   emp.setKeynameschar(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
```

It retrieves the single  Value. 
  How can i retrieve all the three  tag values. 
  I am using StaX parser.
  Thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Your XML is not [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) (`<Number>...</SequenceNumber>` for example). It's not clear what you mean by "three tag values". I presume you want to get all 3 authors.

I don't know how your code is organised. I'd think something like the following would work.

Your class `BookSpecBean` has to have a list of `Author` objects in it. Then you can add as many `Author`s as you find in XML.

```
class BookSpecBean {
  private final List<Author> authors;

  public BookSpecBean() {
    authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
  }

  public void addAuthor(Author a) {
    authors.add(a);
  }

  public List<Author> getAllAuthors() {
    return authors;
  }

  // ... and more fields ...
}

class Author {
  public String getRole() { ... }
  public void setRole(String role) { ... }

  public int getNumber() { ... }
  public void setNumber(int n) { ... }

  // ... and more fields ...
}

class BookSpecXmlReader {
  public BookSpecBean readBookSpec(XMLEventReader reader) {
    BookSpecBean book = new BookSpecBean();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
      if (event.isStartElement()) {
        StartElement startEl = event.asStartElement();
        String elementName = startEl.getName().getLocalPart();
        if (elementName.equals("Author")) {
          book.addAuthor(readAuthor(reader));
        }
      } else if (event.isEndElement()) {
        EndElement endEl = event.asEndElement();
        if (endEl.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Product")) {
          return book;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private Author readAuthor(XMLEventReader reader) {
    Author author = new Author();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
      if (event.isStartElement()) {
        StartElement startEl = event.asStartElement();
        String elementName = startEl.getName().getLocalPart();
        if (startEl.equals("Role")) {
          author.setRole(reader.nextEvent().asCharacters().getData());
        } else if (startEl.equals("Number")) {
          author.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(
              reader.nextEvent().asCharacters().getData()));
        }
      } else if (event.isEndElement()) {
        EndElement endEl = event.asEndElement();
        if (endEl.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Author")) {
          return author;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```